# Extracting value from a group, basing on a condition on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(
  ItemId INT NOT NULL,
  CategoryId INT NOT NULL,
  ItemValue INT NOT NULL
)
```

A table contains items. Every item belongs to a category and stores some numeric value.

As a result of a query, I want each row to represent a category. There should be three columns:

- category id;
- id of an item with the highest `ItemValue` per category;
- id of an item with the lowest `ItemValue` per category.

Performance of the query is important. I use MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+, you can do this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CategoryId ORDER BY ItemValue DESC) MaxRN,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CategoryId ORDER BY ItemValue) MinRN
    FROM Items
)
SELECT  CategoryId, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN MaxRN = 1 THEN ItemId END) IdMaxValue,
        MIN(CASE WHEN MinRN = 1 THEN ItemId END) IdMinValue
FROM CTE
GROUP BY CategoryId;
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ab28/1) where you can test this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a common table expression:

```
WITH CategoryHigh (High, ItemId, CategoryId) 
AS 
(
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryId ORDER BY ItemValue DESC) AS High,
    ItemId,
    CategoryId
FROM Items
),
CategoryLow (Low, ItemId, CategoryId) 
AS
(
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryId ORDER BY ItemValue) AS Low,
    ItemId,
    CategoryId
FROM Items
)
SELECT 
H.CategoryId,
L.ItemId AS LowItem,
H.ItemId AS HighItem
FROM CategoryHigh H
JOIN CategoryLow L ON H.CategoryId = L.CategoryId
WHERE H.High = 1 AND
      L.Low = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Though, Lamak's solution seems to perform better, and it's also shorter, so I'm marking his answer as a accepted.

Comment: Yes, I enjoyed seeing his answer, as I began by trying to have both Row_Number() functions in one CTE as well, but had trouble making it work from there. Thanks for the recognition, though!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
;with 
cte as(
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [CategoryId] order by [ItemValue]) rownum
    from [Items] ),
cte1 as(select [CategoryId],MIN([ItemId]) [min_ItemId]
    from cte where rownum=1
    group by [CategoryId]),
cte2 as(
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [CategoryId] order by [ItemValue]) rownum
    from [Items] ),
cte3 as( 
    select [CategoryId],MAX([ItemId]) [max_ItemId]
    from cte2 C1
    where rownum=(select MAX(rownum) from cte C2 where C1.[CategoryId]=C2.[CategoryId])
    group by [CategoryId])
select A.[CategoryId],A.[min_ItemId],B.[max_ItemId] 
from cte1 A join cte3 B
on A.[CategoryId]=B.[CategoryId]
```